# How to display argument value of list object created by a function

Tags: r, function

I have a function open.account which takes an argument 'total' and creates a list of three functions (deposit, withdraw, balance).  If I run `test <- open.account(100)` how can I access the value of total for test directly without calling one of the list functions?

```
    open.account <- function(total) {
  list(
    deposit = function(amount) {
      if(amount <= 0)
        stop("Deposits must be positive!\n")
      total <<- total + amountw
      cat(amount, "deposited.  Your balance is", total, "\n\n")
    },
    withdraw = function(amount) {
      if(amount > total)
        stop("You don't have that much money!\n")
      total <<- total - amount
      cat(amount, "withdrawn.  Your balance is", total, "\n\n")
    },
    balance = function() {
      cat("Your balance is", total, "\n\n")
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each returned function has its own environment where `total` is stored.

```
g <- open.account(total = 100)

environment(g$deposit)
# <environment: 0x279d0b0>
ls(environment(g$deposit))
# [1] "total"
environment(g$deposit)$total
# [1] 100
```